# Are there words for topological spaces without "special" points?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

What I mean when I say "without 'special' points" is something along the lines of "such that for any pair of points, there is a (disjoint?) pair of respective (connected?) neighborhoods of those points that are homeomorphic/diffeomorphic/isometric/etc." or "such that for every neighborhood of one point and every other point, there is a neighborhood of the second point homeomorphic/etc. to the first neighborhood". The types of space I'm thinking of are ones where inhabitants of the space wouldn't be able to tell where in the space they were (given only the tools being used to study the space); I want to rule out things like manifolds with (non-empty) boundary and spaces with both isolated and non-isolated points, since boundary points and isolated points "look" different to interior points and non-isolated points, respectively.

Comment: A topological space is said to be *homogeneous* if there is a group that acts transitively on it. This implies your "no special points" property but is probably too strict, i.e. I suspect there is a space with no special points but no transitive group action.

Comment: You can call it **locally homogeneous.** This terminology is used in Riemannian geometry for Riemannian manifolds where every two points admit isometric neighborhoods, see [here](https://diffgeom.subwiki.org/wiki/Locally_homogeneous_metric).

Comment: @hunter actually I believe the term *homogenous* should mean (in this case): for any two points $x,y\in X$ there is a homeomorphism $f:X\to X$ such that $f(x)=y$. I'm not sure if this implies that there is a topological group acting continuously and transitively on $X$ (note that $Homeo(X)$ is not a topological group in general, you need some additional assumptions on $X$, e.g. locally compact, locally connected).

Comment: The *locally homogenous* term seems appropriate. I wonder though if this is what OP is looking for. For example every manifold (without boundary) is locally homogenous, but a disconnected manifold does not have to be homogenous, e.g. $S^1\sqcup\mathbb{R}$ is not homogenous. Does this mean that $S^1\sqcup\mathbb{R}$ does not have "special" points? Maybe, but it does have special components (e.g. one of them contractible, the other one not).

Comment: @freakish your definition is the same as asking that Homeo(X) acts transitively on X (as a group with no topology, or as a discrete group if you prefer, note that hunter never mentioned topology or continuity of the action either)

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti hunter does not talk about topology or $Homeo(X)$ at all. But with such approach, for every topological space there is an abstract group acting on it transitively. Thus such definition isn't really useful. We could restrict it to $Homeo(X)$ only and then I agree it is the same thing. My point was that alternative approach is to assume that a topological group acts continuously and transitively. Which I believe (without proof) it is a strictly stronger condition.

Comment: @freakish of course the action has to be by homeomorphisms, any group action on any object is meant to be by isomorphisms of the object in the category it lives in

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti a group action by isomorphisms, but the group itself is not a group object? That sounds a bit exotic to be honest. I've never seen such thing being worked on, I might be wrong though. Perhaps you can point me to some paper?

Comment: @freakish I must be misunderstanding your question, surely people look all the time at, for example, actions by group isomorphisms of a nonabelian group on a group, even though the former is not a group object in the category of groups? Or other similar examples, you don't require a group acting by \*-isomorphisms on a C\*-algebra to be a C\*-algebra itself, let alone a group object in their category

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti nah, you're absolutely right. An example closer to me is simply group representation. Now that I think about it, I'm not really sure why I was confused about it. Thanks for the discussion! :)

Comment: "Homogeneous" is indeed the word I was looking for; I now remember reading it in an informal topology book, but had forgotten about it when I asked. That said, @hunter can you find any examples you'd say count as having no special points but aren't homogeneous?